# User error in accessing result from list created with sapply

Tags: r

I am trying to upload csv files and I am confused on why I am getting different presenting format

For example

```
test1 = read.csv("test1.csv")

  Date    Open    High     Low   Close     Volume Adj.Close
1 2014-04-25 1877.72 1877.72 1859.70 1863.40 3213020000   1863.40
2 2014-04-24 1881.97 1884.06 1870.24 1878.61 3191830000   1878.61
3 2014-04-23 1879.32 1879.75 1873.91 1875.39 3085720000   1875.39
4 2014-04-22 1872.57 1884.89 1872.57 1879.55 3215440000   1879.55
5 2014-04-21 1865.79 1871.89 1863.18 1871.89 2642500000   1871.89
6 2014-04-17 1861.73 1869.63 1856.72 1864.85 3341430000   1864.85
```

If I do this

```
test <- list.files(pattern = "*.csv")
read.all <- sapply(test, read.csv)

head(read.all["test1.csv"])

$test1.csv
       Date    Open    High     Low   Close    Volume Adj.Close
1    2014-04-25 14554.3 14554.3 14472.1 14533.6 149223000  14533.60
2    2014-04-24 14533.4 14584.1 14522.2 14554.3 181767100  14554.30
3    2014-04-23 14556.3 14587.1 14533.4 14533.4 166976100  14533.40
4    2014-04-22 14492.9 14556.6 14471.9 14556.0 159636400  14556.00
5    2014-04-21 14500.4 14509.7 14232.3 14493.7 135970800  14493.70
6    2014-04-17 14446.5 14508.5 14423.7 14500.4 169281200  14500.40
7    2014-04-16 14303.9 14448.6 14303.9 14446.5 196046500  14446.50
8    2014-04-15 14284.4 14355.5 14224.9 14303.9 176427100  14303.90
9    2014-04-14 14257.7 14357.0 14245.5 14284.4 161845500  14284.40
10   2014-04-11 14308.0 14308.0 14221.4 14257.7 159710900  14257.70
11   2014-04-10 14435.6 14444.9 14266.6 14308.0 209549500  14308.00
12   2014-04-09 14372.4 14444.6 14372.4 14435.6 182481700  14435.60
13   2014-04-08 14270.3 14382.8 14251.9 14372.5 161334500  14372.50
14   2014-04-07 14393.1 14393.1 14247.1 14270.3 151538100  14270.
It just keep going
```

also

```
> nrow(test1)
1684
> nrow(read.all["test1.csv"])
NULL
```

Why is the head() and nrow not working?

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at `str(read.all)`. `sapply` returns a (simplified if possible) list. In your case, the data corresponding to each csv are stored in a separate list element. To see the head of the first element, try `head(read.all[[1]])`, `head(read.all[['test1.csv']])`, or `head(read.all$test1.csv)`. Note that you need double square brackets (or dollar sign notation) to access the _contents_ of the list element.

Comment: It's probably `Adj.Close`.  Was it `Adj Close` with a space in between before you read it into R?

Comment: @jbaums thanks, head(read.all[[1]]) worked